# Как подсчитать медиану в разрезе недели и преобразовать дату? pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Мне нужно осуществить действие с помощью библиотеки pandas python
У меня есть датафрейм:

```
     Date     |A_AAA      |A_BBB      |B_BBB|
    __________|___________|___________|______
    24.10.2020|5          |0.6        |17
    __________|___________|___________|______
    25.10.2020|6          |0.7        |20
```

Мне нужно получить получить медиану в разрезе недели для определенного столбца и привести датафрейм к такому виду:

```
     Year     |Week       |A_AAA |A_BBB|B_BBB|
    __________|___________|______|_____|______
    2020      |31         |срзнач|срзнач|срзнач
    __________|___________|______|______|______
    2020      |32         |срзнач|срзнач|срзнач
```

Не знаю, как. Подскажите плиз

Comment: @Akina изменила

Comment: Ну опять дайте же исходных данных.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерный df:

```
          date         A         B
0   2020-01-01  0.312451  0.968500
1   2020-01-02  0.243430  0.314655
2   2020-01-03  0.790279  0.869671
3   2020-01-04  0.365604  0.682645
4   2020-01-05  0.917735  0.588230
..         ...       ...       ...
361 2020-12-27  0.225481  0.760843
362 2020-12-28  0.771604  0.435545
363 2020-12-29  0.227772  0.647130
364 2020-12-30  0.136732  0.873870
365 2020-12-31  0.976508  0.211952
```

тогда:

```
res = df.assign(year=df["date"].dt.year, week=df["date"].dt.week).groupby("week").mean()
```

res, соответственно, будет:

```
            A         B  year
week                          
1     0.525900  0.684740  2020
2     0.708308  0.237837  2020
3     0.395369  0.367839  2020
4     0.584314  0.556200  2020
5     0.454147  0.665559  2020
6     0.400422  0.446337  2020
7     0.493830  0.329452  2020
8     0.381090  0.483078  2020
9     0.566580  0.480643  2020
10    0.652646  0.543519  2020
11    0.467229  0.470082  2020
12    0.478662  0.502610  2020
13    0.448953  0.510073  2020
14    0.404982  0.468422  2020
... # и т. д.
```

Answer (score 0):

Если я вас правильно понял

```
# Подготовка данных
data = pd.DataFrame([{'Date': '2020-10-24', 'A_AAA': 1, 'A_BBB': 2, 'B_BBB' :3}, {'Date': '2020-11-25', 'A_AAA': 1, 'A_BBB': 2, 'B_BBB' :3}])
data['Date'] = data['Date'].astype('datetime64')

# Вытаскиваем год и неделю
data['year'] = data['Date'].dt.year
data['week'] = data['Date'].dt.week

# Группировка данных
data.groupby(by=['year', 'week']).agg({'A_AAA': np.median, 'A_BBB': np.median, 'B_BBB': np.median})
```